# Store and retrieve correct data

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I want to create a form for selecting a number of receiving then that's the reference items store correctly and retrieve correctly.
 [image]

this is my angular js code

```
$scope.addreciveditemtemp = function(receiving,newreciveditemtemp) {
  $scope.receiving_item = [ ];
  $http.get('api/reciveditem').success(function(response) {
      $scope.receiving_item = response;
      for (var i=0;i<$scope.receiving_item.length;i++){
          var receiving_item = $scope.receiving_item[i];
          if(receiving_item.receiving_id===receiving.id){
              console.log(receiving_item);
              $http.post('api/reciveditemtemp', {
                 recived_id: receiving_item.receiving_id,
                 item_id: receiving_item.item_id,
                 cost_price: receiving_item.cost_price,
                 prequantity: receiving_item.quantity,
                 pretotal_cost: receiving_item.total_cost,
                 realtotal: receiving_item.total_cost
              }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                 $scope.reciveditemtemp.push(data);
                 $http.get('api/reciveditemtemp').success(function(data) {
                     $scope.reciveditemtemp = data;                
                 });
              });
           }  
       } 
  });
};
```

this is my laravel controller code

```
public function store()
    { $this->newItem();
}

public function newItem()
{
    $receiving_item = ReceivingItem::where('receiving_id', Input::get('item_id'))->get();
    foreach($receiving_item as $value)
    {

        $reciveditemtemps = new reciveditemtemp;
        $reciveditemtemps->recived_id = $value->receiving_id;
        $reciveditemtemps->item_id = $value->item_id;
        $reciveditemtemps->cost_price = $value->cost_price;
        $reciveditemtemps->prequantity = $value->quantity;
        $reciveditemtemps->pretotal_cost = $value->total_cost;
        $reciveditemtemps->realquantity = $value->quantity;
        $reciveditemtemps->realtotal = $value->cost_price * $value->realquantity;
        $reciveditemtemps->save();
        //return $ReceivingTemps;
    }
        return $reciveditemtemps;
}
```

But console answer is correct
[image]

how to solve this problem?? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the controller code.

```
public function newItem()
{ 
   $reciveditemtemps = new reciveditemtemp;
   $reciveditemtemps->recived_id = Input::get('receiving_id');
   $reciveditemtemps->item_id = Input::get('item_id');
   $reciveditemtemps->cost_price = Input::get('cost_price');
   $reciveditemtemps->prequantity = Input::get('prequantity');
   $reciveditemtemps->pretotal_cost = Input::get('pretotal_cost');  
   $reciveditemtemps->realtotal = Input::get('realtotal');
   $reciveditemtemps->realquantity = Input::get('prequantity');
   $reciveditemtemps->save();
   return $reciveditemtemps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks sketchy:

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
>  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
>      $scope.reciveditemtemp.push(data);
>      $http.get('api/reciveditemtemp').success(function(data) {
>          $scope.reciveditemtemp = data;                
>      });
>   });
> ```

To push a value to an array and then replace the entire array does not seem right.

Comment: what is the difference with my code? This sketchy is same as my code

Comment: That's the point they were making @A.lakkantha . You push to reciveditemtemp and then replace it.